Re-enabling [htbp] commands in float package when utilising a predefined latex template
Currently I'm in the process of writing my dissertation using the latex template for the Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society (MNRAS) journal. The graphicx and float packages are loaded within my source file, however the htbp commands are disabled within the template itself (info confirmed in their guide for authors document) on account of the reviewers and publishers handling formatting - MWE attached and source files linked.
Given the context of a dissertation, I require the ability to specify figure and table placement prior to any potential publishing stage, but I'm not sure how to edit the .bst or .cls files (or any other template file relevant to my issue) in a manner that re-enables the float commands and doesn't destroy my ability to compile using the template since
Template info: https://academic.oup.com/mnras/pages/general_instructions
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monthly-notices-of-the-royal-astronomical-society-mnras-latex-template-and-guide-for-authors/kqnjzrwjwjth
MWE:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{dummy}
    \caption{Enter Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

Outcome: rendered figure/table with [H] off to the side
Excerpt from class file:
% Settings for how much of the page can be used for floats
\setcounter{topnumber}{4}
\def\topfraction{0.9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\def\bottomfraction{0.5}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{3} % two-column floats
\def\dbltopfraction{0.9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
\def\textfraction{0.1}
\def\floatpagefraction{0.9}
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{0.9}

\newif\ifst@rredfloat
\newcounter{table}
\def\thetable{\@arabic\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{1}
\def\fstyle@table{\reset@font\small\rm}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{Table \thetable}
\def\table{\def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \let\@makecaption=\SFB@maketablecaption%
  \@float{table}\fstyle@table}
\let\endtable\end@float
\@namedef{table*}{\def\baselinestretch{1}\st@rredfloattrue
  \let\@makecaption=\SFB@maketablecaption%
  \@dblfloat{table}\centering\fstyle@table}
\@namedef{endtable*}{\end@dblfloat\st@rredfloatfalse}

\newcounter{figure}
\def\thefigure{\@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fps@figure{tbp}
\def\ftype@figure{2}
\def\fstyle@figure{\reset@font\small\rm}
\def\ext@figure{lof}
\def\fnum@figure{Figure \thefigure}
\def\figure{\def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \let\@makecaption=\SFB@makefigurecaption%
  \@float{figure}\fstyle@figure}
\let\endfigure\end@float
\@namedef{figure*}{\def\baselinestretch{1}\st@rredfloattrue
  \let\@makecaption=\SFB@makefigurecaption%
  \@dblfloat{figure}\centering\fstyle@figure}
\@namedef{endfigure*}{\end@dblfloat\st@rredfloatfalse}

Thanks in advance guys?
